# promise is not resolved at controller injection

Tags: angularjs, controller, promise, inject, resolve

I'm facing an issue. I'm working with angular 1.2RC3 and ui-route 0.2.
If i resolve with a function which is doing a synchronous return, it works.
With a promise, the controller is initialized before resolving the promise.

http://plnkr.co/edit/feXHNaGsXwpXDBXkxLZx

```
angular.module('srcApp', ['ui.router'])
    .config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

        var userResult = {
            id : 'userid',
            displayName : 'displayName'
        };

        var getUserPromise = function ($q, $timeout, $log) {

            var defer = $q.defer;
            $timeout(function () {
                $log.log('promise resolved');
                defer.resolve(userResult);
            }, 2000);
            return defer.promise;
        };

        $stateProvider.state('test', {
            url: '/',
            template: '<div>{{user.displayName}}</div>',
            controller: 'testCtrl',
            resolve : {
              user: getUserPromise
            }
        });
    });


    var testCtrl = angular.module('srcApp').controller('testCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $log, user) {
        $log.log("test controller init");
        $log.log("test controller user=" + user);
        $scope.user = user;
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Weird... It's pretty much what I do line for line in an app.

Solved: http://plnkr.co/edit/oC5wK8aDcq82mWl8ES6l?p=preview

You typed:

```
$q.defer
```

instead of:

```
$q.defer()
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm just beginning with pure JS, i'm not afraid to be ridiculous to get started faster ;)!